# Computing $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}[x]/(x-a)^n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, automorphism-group

How do I find $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}[x]/(x-a)^n)$ as $\mathbb{C}[x]$ module? Does it have a reasonable description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $\mathbb C[x]$-automorphisms.

First we will just classify all the endomorphisms, and the identify the automorphisms within there. The module of endomorphisms simply isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x]/(x-a)^n$ itself.

The more general fact is that for a ring $A$ and ideal $I$, the module of endomorphisms of $A/I$ as $A$-module is isomorphic to $A/I$ itself. This is simply because every endomorphism is determined by where it sends $1$ (or rather the class of $1$) and conversely for every such choice one obtains an endomorphism (multiplication by that element).

Under this identification, an endomorphism is an automorphism exactly when it corresponds to multiplication by a unit. The units of $\mathbb C[x]/ (x-a)^n$ are quite easy to classify because it is a local ring with maximal ideal $(x-a)$. The units are the complement of that ideal, which are all elements of the form
$$c + g(x)(x-a)^n$$
for $c$ a nonzero complex number.

Comment: Automorphisms, not endomorphisns.

Comment: Just take the units then. Your ring is local with an easy to describe maximal ideal $(x-a)$ and the units are the complement of that. I will edit that in shortly.